# Prove that $ (\forall A)\bigcup\mathcal P(A) = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that  $ (\forall A)\bigcup\mathcal P(A) = A$ where $\mathcal P(X)$ is the power set of $X$. I tried to evaluate it like this: 
$$x\in \mathcal \bigcup \mathcal P(A) \iff (\exists B\in\mathcal P(A) )(x \in B)$$
Now,  I don't know how to continue from here - I could not find a formal definition of the power set and so I could not eliminate it from the formula. How should I continue?

Comment: For all $x \in A$, $\{x\} \in \mathcal P(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove a set equality it's often easiest to prove two subset relations.

$$\bigcup P(A) \subseteq A$$

$$A \subseteq \bigcup P(A) $$

To prove the first of these we might say

$$x\in \bigcup P(A)$$
$$\exists C\in P(A). x\in C $$
$$\exists C\subseteq A. x\in C$$
$$x \in A$$

And to prove the second a sensible approach might be
$$x\in A$$
$$\{x\} \subseteq A$$
$$\{x\} \in P(A)$$
$$x \in \bigcup P(A)$$

Comment: How do you know that $\{ x \} \subseteq A $ ?

Comment: If x is in A, then so is every member of $\{x\}$ (since the only member is x) and therefore by definition $\{x\}$ is a subset of A.

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $A$, in order to prove that $\bigcup \mathcal{P}(A) = A$, you need to prove that
$$x \in \bigcup \mathcal{P}(A) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x \in A$$
You have correctly identified that $x \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ if and only if $x \in B$ for some $B \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. Now $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the set of all subsets $B \subseteq A$, which means that
$$B \in \mathcal{P}(A) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \forall y(y \in B \Rightarrow y \in A)$$
So if you know that $x \in B$ for some $B \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, then it follows that $x \in A$.

Hopefully you can take it from here, but let me know in the comments if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

> I could not find a formal definition of the power set and so I could not eliminate it from the formula.

A powerset of a set is the set of all subsets of that set (including that set).   $\mathcal P(A)=\{B: B\subseteq A\}$

From which it follow that the arbitrary union of the powerset of a set must be that set.   Since every element of any subset of that set is an element of that set, and that set is a subset of itself, then the set of elements of any subset of that set is the set of elements of that set; that is that set.

$$\bigcup\mathcal P(A) {= \bigcup \{B : B\subseteq A\} \\=\{x:\exists B: x\in B,B\subseteq A\} \\= \{x\in A\} \\= A}$$